# python 2.7 compatibility issue with 11th Gen Intel Core i9?

Tags: python, windows, crash, maya, pymysql

I know Python 2.7 reached the end of life one year ago but unfortunately inside the Autodesk Maya version that we still using in some productions we have only that one and we can't change it.

The issue is happening only on two brand new machines with the: 11th Gen Intel Core i9-11900K @ 3.50GHz processor.
Just running the most simple connection to an mySql database:

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host='myHostname', user='myUserName', password='myPassword', db='databaseName', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

the python shell it's closing without any error, while on other older three hundred machines it works from several years.

Moving from Python 2.7.10 to 2.7.18 the issue is solved on Windows, but still the crash happening inside Maya where Python is fixed to 2.7.11.

Any idea or suggestion to avoid this annoying crash?

If it will still remain not understood we have no other choice of moving to an higher Maya version with Python 3, but then could be other issues unfortunately with hundreads of functions written in Python 2.7, I'm just wondering if we can find a kind of workaround on these two machines.
Thanks

Comment: This is more like an alternative than a solution, but how extensive is your integration? Might be as good a time as any to set up a REST-style API server as a gateway between your clients and the database, if you're into that sort of thing :)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, we already have a sort of API for the database connection, so if I find another module that makes a successful connection I don't have to change too much python files I guess. But now I'm afraid that could be more python modules affected by the crash reading this post from Autodesk forum:  https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-forum/faulting-module-crash/m-p/10562895

Answer (score 1):

Solution founded from here:

https://support.foundry.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012750300-Q100573-Katana-Mari-and-Nuke-can-fail-to-launch-with-a-10th-or-11th-Generation-Intel-CPU

Basically it is a bug coming from OpenSSL on Windows:

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/openssl-sha-crash-bug-requires-application-update.html